# After .showdialog() is run, is there a way to let the user still at least min/max/move the parent window?

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, show, showdialog

I was able to get this behavior with the .show() call but the new form would no longer work properly in terms of updating plots like with how .showdialog() still allowed. Is there a trivial way to still let the user move, maximize, and/or minimize the parent window after .showdialog() is executed?

Comment: The purpose of `.ShowDialog()` is to **block** parent window, while user is dealing with child. So, no, you need to use `.Show()` and somehow deal with your plots.

Comment: You may be able to use `.Show()` and just use the `Window.Closed` event handler to process the data that was put into the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following code. This way the form stays on top while you can still access the parent form.

```
CalledForm.TopMost = true;
CalledForm.Owner = CallerForm;
CalledForm.Show();
```